# Jupyter Notebook: custom.js is not read

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0, in Python 2.7,  on Windows 7. I have created *%HOMEPATH%.jupyter\custom\custom.js* file and added the following code to turn off **autosave**.

```
define([
  'base/js/events'
  ],
  function(IPython, events) {
    events.on("notebook_loaded.Notebook",
      function () {
        IPython.notebook.set_autosave_interval(0); // Disable autosave
      }
      // Additional events.on() statements here
    );
  }
);
```

Unfortunately, it has no effect on **autosave**. However, the problem is not with the code (which one can find in various places), but the fact that Notebook does seem to even read *custom.js*, neither when the Notebook server starts nor when I open a ipynb file. Further actions I did:

1) I verified that it can find and read it using the appropriate Python code.
2) I added an alert() message in *custom.js* which is never shown
3) I added the following as an alternative for turning **autosave** off: `Jupyter.notebook.set_autosave_interval(0);` that I saw in some other post in stackoverflow.com.

Of course, none of these will have any effect if Notebook never reads *custom.js*. Any idea why is that happening?

... One day later:

I cleaned **custom.js** leaving only `Jupyter.notebook.set_autosave_interval(0);` *Autosave* is finally turned off! (So, most probably Notebook didn't like something in **custom.js** and rejected it totally!)

So I consider this question solved.